# Using VBA to make a cell update a OLAP filter in a pivot table on another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I'm a newbie to VBA and am having trouble getting a cell to change a filter on another worksheet's Pivot Table. It should be noted that the Pivot Table is attached to an OLAP cube. The closest I have gotten is:

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

 If Intersect(Target, Range("c2")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
 Dim pt As PivotTable
 Dim Field As PivotField
 Dim NewCat As String

 Set pt = Worksheets("16 Previous Month YTD").PivotTables("PivotTable1")
 Set Field = pt.PivotFields("[Accounting Periods].[Year].[Year]")
 NewCat = Worksheets("16 Previous Month YTD").Range("c2").Value

 ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields( _
"[Accounting Periods].[Year].[Year]").VisibleItemsList = Array( _
"[Accounting Periods].[Year].&[2.014E3]")

 End Sub
```

This will run a macro that obviously changes the filter to 2014, but I want it to change based on value C2 of another sheet.